# Return value from different table based on range

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have a main table in SQL Server containing some percentages of progress per each month

| Jan % | Feb % | Mar % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16.25 | 19.56 | 25.09 |
| 52.01 | 62.22 | 71.05 |
| 84.72 | 92.76 | 100.00 |

And a second table which gives me the corrected progression, per ranges.

| New % | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.60 | 0.00 | 0.20 |
| 0.75 | 0.20 | 0.40 |
| 0.81 | 0.30 | 0.50 |
| 0.89 | 0.50 | 0.70 |
| 0.93 | 0.70 | 1.00 |

I have to basically return next to current progression percentages, the New% for each column.

I know that a JOIN could be used, in the lines of:

```
LEFT JOIN RAW.New_Comp ON [Jan %] BETWEEN [Start]*100 AND [End]*100
```

But how can I write this in an easy and efficient way so I would not need to write a JOIN for every single month?

Comment: what is the relation between these 2 tables ? If you know the relation you can join them, and when you don't want to write the join every time again, write the join inside a view, then just call the view instead

Comment: @GuidoG I do like your suggestion of view ( I wouldn't have thought of that)! I've been actually trying a second method, of UNPIVOT-ing the first table and then trying to LEFT JOIN the new_comp. However, it is causing duplicates (giving 2 New % per progression sometimes) I thought it was due to the boundaries of BETWEEN being inclusive and changed the ranges (0.00 to 0.20 then 0.21 to 0.40, etc) but it's still duplicating. Mind, I'm testing it on a larger dataset and it's only problematic for 4k lines out of 200k,

Comment: That is a different problem than you wrote in your question, I suggest you write a new question and explain this problem, provide it with sample data that will reproduce the problem and show us what you expect as result. Also don't forget to mention what you have tried, and where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to write the join every time again, then write a view an use that view instead

See [this DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j8kQeUEr)

write your view like this for example (I don't know the relation between your table, so I just took your join example for this)

```
create view vwMainAndValue as
  select m.jan,
         m.feb,
         m.mar,
         c.newp, 
         c.startv,
         c.endv
  from   main m
    left join new_comp c on m.jan between c.startv * 100 and c.endv * 100
```

and then just call the view like a normal table

```
select * from vwMainAndValue
```